# What is a $\Delta$-structure of $S^1\times S^1$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I understand that this is two triangles and how we glue together the sides and vertices since $S^1\times S^1$ is $T^2$. However, when giving a $\Delta$-structure, do I need to provide the maps? I think maybe this involves a pushout, the maps are the part I don't understand.

Comment: Could you define what you call a "$\Delta-$structure"?

Comment: If what you're looking for is something like a simplicial complex, or a CW complex, then what exactly you need to provide is entirely up to whoever is reading / correcting whatever it is you're writing. Is it enough to just draw a picture of a square with some triangles in it, or do you need explicit function expressions for all the embeddings? We can't answer that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to provide the maps.

The following is not how Hatcher does it, but it is equivalent.

First you need to provide a family of sets: the set $K_n$ of $n$-simplices for $n=0, 1,2, ...$. (In your case, just $n=0,1,2$.) Then you also need to provide "face maps" connecting those sets: $d_i: K_n \to K_{n-1}$ for $i=0,...,n$. For example the two maps $d_i: K_1 \to K_0$, $i=0,1$, send an edge to its two endpoints, and part of the structure of a $\Delta$-complex is to specify which is the 0th and which is the 1st endpoint: the faces of each simplex are ordered. In order for this to be a valid $\Delta$-complex structure, the identity
$$
d_i d_j = d_{j-1} d_i \text{ for all } i<j
$$
must be satisfied.

The previous paragraph gives what might be called an "abstract" $\Delta$-complex or a $\Delta$-set: there is no topology yet. Then you can define its *geometric realization* by taking, for each element of $K_n$, an $n$-simplex, and then gluing the various simplices together using the face maps. This gives what Hatcher calls a $\Delta$-complex.

See for example Greg Friedman's article https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.4221.pdf, section 2.4 for Delta sets and section 4 for realization.